# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/CoderProviderRegistrar

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-beam, dataproc

I'm getting this error while trying to submit a shaded jar to dataproc as a spark job :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/CoderProviderRegistrar
```

I'm sure that this class exists. Where is the issue?

Stacktrace Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: yeah, I'm seeing the same error with beam 2.50.0 on dataproc 2.1.  any luck root causing this?

Comment: @Ahmed How can might this issue be reproduced? Is there perhaps a public repository branch that I can download to try and reproduce this?

Comment: @fruitJuice Do you have codebase to reproduce this issue? If you have, then please share it via github

Comment: I got the error solved but i don't know if it's the right way to do it .
I have put the shaded jar of my application that contains all the dependencies in /usr/lib/spark/jars
and it worked

Answer (score 2):

[According to Official Apache Beam Docs on Spark Runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/#deploying-spark-with-your-application):

> Support for Spark 2.4.x was dropped with Beam 2.46.0 from Spark Runner 3.2 onwards

This means that **Beam 2.50.0** and **Spark 2.4.x** is not available in your current **Spark Runner** version.

Try these dependencies by adding `beam-runners-spark-3`, `apache-streaming` and `apache-core`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-spark-3</artifactId>
  <version>2.50.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer to the docs more info as it has complete step - by - step process on how to setup and make it running.

**Note:** It has Maven shade plugin example and dataproc example too.